# Best way to optimize a nested select that invokes a costly function

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL right now, i am interested only in 100 records to be fetched. Say my table has 100k records. Fetch these records subject to the condition that  we are optimal.

current SQL:

```
Select a,b,c from table where SomeCostlyFunction(,,) > T1 
LIMIT 100;
```

I want to introduce another check based on SomeCostlyFunction(,,,)

**option#1**

```
Select a,b,c from table 
where SomeCostlyFunction(,,) > T1 AND SomeCostlyFunction(a,b,c) < T2
LIMIT 100;
```

**option#2**

```
Select a,b,c from 
  (Select a,b,c, SomeCostlyFunction(a,b,c) as func_val from table)
where func_val > T1 AND func_val < T2
LIMIT 100;
```

**Doubts:**

1. In option#1 SomeCostlyFunction() will be called twice more compared to baseline.
2. But in option#2 because of the nested select will SomeCostlyFunction() be called 100k times ? I am only interested in getting 100 records.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Have a look at the execution plan.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: If you are using Postgres, it depends on whether the function is marked as `stable`, `volatile` or `immutable`